# Project from 2D to 3D with Three.js

Tags: three.js

How would I project 2D coordinates on to 3D?

For example I have an image (represented as a particle) that is 256px wide. If I pretend this image is centered on the origin (0,0) in 2D space then the vertical sides of the square are located at x = 128 and x = -128.

So when this image(particle) is placed in a Three.js scene at the origin(0,0) and the camera is at CamZ distance from the origin, then how do I project the original 2D coordinates to 3D which in tern will tell me the width the image(particle!) appears on screen in three.js units.

Comment: The way this is usually handled is by dividing by the z-value, so you can imagine the x-values you have getting smaller by dividing by higher and higher z-values. However you are actually dividing by some factor of the z-value and your field of view is going to effect it. Not sure how to extrapolate the width you need from that however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy to understand way would be creating a geometry with vertices in `-128, 128, 0`, `128, 128, 0`, `-128, -128, 0` and `128, -128, 0`. Then use `Projector` for projecting that geometry using the camera. It will give you an array of projected points that should be from -1 to 1. You'll then need to multiply that to the viewport size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I've been a little stupid. I built a mesh with vertices (128,-128), (128, 128), (-128, 128), (-128, 128) as you suggested and then bang the resultant square is the same size as the particle. So particle sizes in three.js are just the original mapped image size * scale :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it. The exact translation between 2D and 3D can be approximated heuristically. Often it is more difficult to implement than using three.js to project a vector, but with an exponential translation you can map many 2D/3D translations.

The idea here is to use an Exponential easing function to calculate the translation. The easing functions that most libraries use (such as jQuery UI) are the [Robert Penner Easing functions](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/).

The easeOutExpo function works surprisingly well at approximating 2D/3D translations. Generally it would look something like this:

```
// easeOutExpo(time, base, change, duration)
var xPosition3D = xPosition2D * expo(xPosition2D, 0, coefficient, xMax2D);
```

It takes a co-efficient, and the exact number will depend on the aspect ratio and focal length of the 3D camera. Usually, something like -.2 works well.

I know this is an insufficient explanation, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.